# Protocol-oriented files fetching

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

Recently I watched this talk ([link](https://realm.io/news/appbuilders-natasha-muraschev-practical-protocol-oriented-programming/), see section *Networking*) and I decided to do some excerise in protocol-oriented programming. So I thought about this simple example: View Controller for displaying list of files. Of course, protocol-oriented way, with following constraints:

`FilesViewController` - containts table view & `FilesTableViewAdapter`. Table view delegate.
`FilesTableViewAdapter` - initializable with table view & `FilesProvider: Gettable`,
so that in tests I can inject `FilesProviderMock: Gettable`.
`FilesTableViewAdapter` is a data source of table view and uses `FilesProvider` for fetching files.

```
final class FilesTableViewController: UIViewController {

    var filesTableView: FilesTableView! { return view as! FilesTableView }

    private var tableViewAdapter: FilesTableViewAdapter<FilesProvider>!

    // MARK: Subclassing

    override func loadView() {
        view = FilesTableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       tableViewAdapter = FilesTableViewAdapter(filesTableView.tableView, provider: FilesProvider())

       // Actually I would like to have this method in Adapter
       // so that VC isn't handling networking.
       tableViewAdapter.provider.get { result in
           // result type: (Result<[File]>)
           switch result {
           case .success(let files): print(files)
           case .failure(let error): print(error)
           }
        }

        filesTableView.tableView.delegate = self
        filesTableView.tableView.dataSource = tableViewAdapter
     }
}

extension FilesTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
  //
}


final class FilesTableViewAdapter<T: Gettable>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    let provider: T
    private let tableView: UITableView

    init(_ tableView: UITableView, provider: T) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.provider = provider

        super.init()
    }

    func problem() {
        provider.get { result in
            // Result type is (Result<T.T>) - :(
            switch result {
            case .success(let files): print(files)
            case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct FilesProvider {
   private let Files = [File]()
}

extension FilesProvider: Gettable {

    func get(completionHandler: (Result<[File]>) -> Void) {
        //
    }
}

protocol Gettable {
   associatedtype T
   func get(completionHandler: (Result<T>) -> Void)
}
```

I know I went too far with *generalizing* this piece of code. Now I'm stuck and I have this questions I can't answer myself:

1. How to make it in protocol-oriented way, with networking code in class different than VC (say *Adapter*)?
2. How to make it easily testable and extendable in the future?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create something similar as I did with my [OFAPopulator](http://vikingosegundo.github.io/ofapopulator/) — though still in objective-c.